# 9M resistance on a mixer / DSP interface board

Tags: oscilloscope

[image]I am redesigning an old board we have for supporting a signal processing course. It allows students to connect several signal inputs and route them to a DSP board (through 3.5mm aux cable) an an oscilloscope (through BNC connectors).

The original board design has a switch which allows the user to select 10X impedance on the board itself -- essentially, selecting whether the signal to the BNC first goes through a 9 megaohm resistance. The probes we use are also 10X -- and likely always will be.

I'm trying to figure out if I need the switch on the new board, if I need the resistance, or if I need neither. In theory the oscilloscope is capable of being attached to a circuit at any point, and shouldn't need impedance matching... yes? Does the impedance matching provide any particular benefit in this situation? Could I leave it off the board entirely? If keeping the resistance is recommended, could I remove the switch? Or are there cases where having that option is still necessary?

Comment: There... sorry! I got ahead of myself. There are switches that switch a 9M resistance into the circuit.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but having 9 MOhms into BNC (50 Ohms) makes no sense (180000:1 attenuation) unless you plan to measure 100-kV signals, which again doesn't make much sense if the signals go to a "DSP".

Comment: @AliChen the impedance of the scope is likely 1M, not 50 ohms. This looks like a usual 10x probe.

Comment: @immibis, a 1M input would likely have 20pF, so with 9 MOhms it will make a 10-kHz probe (if no compensation is used). This is not much, especially for demonstrating DSP effects. Making a good 10:1 probe requires some engineering.

Comment: I just realized something that may help: the board that is drawn here has through-hole BNC connectors which are connected to an oscilloscope using standard coaxial cable, not an oscilloscope probe. Could the original designer have added the 9M resistors as a way to make the coax cable look like a probe?